# Save a form using django's authentication framework?

Tags: django, forms, authentication, post, view

I'd like to be able to save data submitted by the form based on the user that is signed in (instead of having the user to write his/her name through a textbox). I am using django's built-in authentication system.  Any thoughts on how I can accomplish this?

```
@login_required 
def add_review(request, product_id):
    p = get_object_or_404(Productbackup, pk=product_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ReviewbackupForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            review = form.save(commit=False)
            review.product = p
            #how to save user as well?  review.user = user
            review.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('reserve.views.view_reviews', kwargs={'product_id':p.id}))
    else:
        form = ReviewbackupForm()
    variables = RequestContext(request, {'form': form, 'product_id': product_id})
    return render_to_response('reserve/templates/create_review.html', variables)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've using save with `commit=False` so you're almost there. You can get the logged in user from the request object.

```
if form.is_valid(): 
    review = form.save(commit=False) 
    review.product = p 
    review.user = request. user 
    review.save()
```

For more details,  see the [Django docs for user authentication](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#authentication-in-web-requests).